# How to have Android AlarmManager do a setWindow but allow while idle?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-workmanager

I need a way to run something during a time window even if the device is idle and in doze mode.
It seems AlarmManger's setExactAndAllowWhileIdle would do the trick.  However, I'd like to conserve battery and I don't need it run at an exact time, a window would do.  From the reading I've done, I don't think AlarmManager's setWindow would initiate anything if the device is in doze mode during the window.  Although I don't need it run at an exact time, I do need it run during the window even if idle.

Is there a common way to do this?

I've thought of doing a setWindow using my windowStart and windowLength, and then doing a setExactAndAllowWhileIdle for windowStart+windowLength.
If the setWindow is called (the device wasn't idle) then I'd have it cancel the setExactAndAllowWhileIdle.
But is there a better way to accomplish this?

I also considered WorkManager, but understand if my acceptable time window is during device idle/doze, it won't run until the doze is over.